# Tidy code for a sequence of jQuery animations on different elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm currently using this code, and it does what I want it to

```
$('#about-link').click(function() {
    $('#login').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#about').fadeIn(function() {
            $('#about').one('click', function() {
                $('#about').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#login').fadeIn();
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
})
```

However, the  amount of nesting there is insane. Is there are way to write this in a less nested way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) does exactly what I was looking for. Very clean:

```
var about = $('#about');
$('#login')
    .fadeOut()
    .queue(function(next) { about.fadeIn(next);       })
    .queue(function(next) { about.one('click', next); })
    .queue(function(next) { about.fadeOut(next);      })
    .fadeIn();
```

Heck, it's even shorted if you're willing to drop browser support:

```
var about = $('#about');
$('#login')
    .fadeOut()
    .queue(about.fadeIn.bind(about))
    .queue(about.one.bind(about, 'click'))
    .queue(about.fadeOut.bind(about))
    .fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#about-link, #about').on('click', function() {
    var el = this.id == 'about-link' ? 'login' : this.id;
    show_hide(el);
    return false;
});

function show_hide(el){
 var arr = ['login', 'about'],
     t = arr.indexOf(el) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $('#' + el).fadeOut(function() {
       $('#' + arr[t]).fadeIn();
    });
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dzn79/6/)**

Comment: Doesn't work. The `one` handler needs to be attached every time the about box becomes visible.

Comment: @Eric Check my new answer with DEMO.

Answer (score 0):

you can move the .one('click') out from the nested function save you one less inner function.

```
$('#about-link').click(function() {
    $('#login').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#about').fadeIn().one('click', function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                $('#login').fadeIn();
            });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That results in a different sequence though. I was thinking that `queue` might help in some way.

Comment: you cannot click anyway until the fadeIn complete so you can add this attribute while the animation takes place. anyway you can refactor it using then() syntax as well: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: Ooh, that look interesting. Care to show me how to use it here?